# Getting error while calling a soap service in OSB via service callout

Tags: java, web-services, soap, osb

I am getting below error when calling a soap service in OSB via service callout.

" **General runtime error: no top level SOAP body element found!** "

Can anyone please tell me the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and resolved it.

Actually, the variable name for the 'Body' in  Service Callout >> Configuration >> Configure Body >> Body* was different from the name of body variable which I was using in 'replace' action.

After I changed the body variable name in service callout, and gave Body* = body and used 'body', then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you're not sending an actual `<soap:Body>` in the envelope. This commonly happens when replacing the entire `$body` by mistake (instead of the *contents* of $body) in a Replace action.

Comment: In the replace action, I am using 'replace node contents' in replace option. I believe that's what you are suggesting. If yes then I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Add execution tracing, discover exactly what gets sent and received, and update your question with the results.